# Dynamically passing of parameter in rails sql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Below is an SQL query which fetches some data related to user.

```
def self.get_user_details(user_id)

      result = Event.execute_sql("select replace(substring_index(properties, 'text', -1),'}','') as p, count(*) as count
                  from ahoy_events e where e.user_id = ?
                  group by p order by count desc limit 5", :user_id)

      return result
 end
```

I want to dynamically pass values to user id to get the result. 
I am using the below method to sanitize sql array, but still it returns no result. The query works fine if given static parameter.

```
   def self.execute_sql(*sql_array)     
       connection.execute(send(:sanitize_sql_array, sql_array))
    end
```

Because the query is complicated I am couldn't figure out the ActiveRecord way to get the results.
Is there any way I could get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that should not work. May SQL-Syntac `SELECT * FROM users ...`

dynamic passing some other way you can do this: `"some string #{user.id#ruby code} some more string"`

You can do querys in Activerecord like this: `User.where(id: user.id).where(field2: value2).group_by(:somevalue).order(:id)`